# amperes too low on this circuit

Tags: power, current-measurement, three-phase, multisim

I'm trying to get the voltage between phases, the line current and the apparent, real and reactive power of the next circuit:
[image]

but there are a  few things dazzling me, the most important is why the line current is so low?

I was expecting something like 10A based on the next calculations:
\$V_{ab}=219.97V\$

\$I_{an}=\frac{V_{an}}{Z_{T}}\$

\$V_{an}=127\angle0\,V\$

\$Z_{T}=10\,\Omega+Z_{L}||Z_{C}\$

\$f=60\,Hz\$

\$Z_{L}||Z_{C}=\frac{1}{|\frac{1}{\omega L}-\omega C|}=\frac{1}{|\frac{1}{2\pi(60)(0.796)}-2\pi(60)(8.84\mu F)|}=0.3000\angle-90\Omega\$

\$Z_{T}=10\,\Omega+0.3000\angle-90=10.0044\angle-1.7183\Omega\$

\$I_{an}=\frac{V_{an}}{Z_{T}}=\frac{127\angle0}{10.0044\angle-1.7183}=12.6944\angle1.7183\,A\$

But then why the current registered is so low? (and then the power and the strange power factor).
I don't get the reason, the circuit has been double checked to avoid misfits in the connections; the system is balanced.
I was expecting the inductance and capacitance impedance cancel each other and only gets a real charge with a power factor of 1 (+90-90).

Comment: Your circuit LC circuit will have a resonance at 60Hz. Thus, Zc||ZL = 00

Comment: @G36, then the current will be more like the 10-12A not the uA, also how did you know the resonant frequency?

Comment: But you have a parallel resonance, thus at F_res Zc||ZL =00 (infinity). And resonance frequency is \$F = \frac{1}{2\pi \sqrt{LC}} = \frac{1}{2\pi \sqrt{0.796H * 8.84 \mu F}} = 60Hz\$  https://tinyurl.com/yjvnv9fs

Comment: Then the small current could be interpreted as the result of  a short circuit?, this would add to the idea of the current being too few, since the only impedance is coming from the resistence/

Comment: The exact calculation shows that the magnitude of a \$ Z_L || Z_C \$ is  \$ Z_L || Z_C = 4.72M \Omega\$ thus, \$Z_T = 4.72M \Omega  \$ and \$I = \frac{127V}{4.72M \Omega} = 27 \mu A\$

Comment: At parallel resonance LC circuit behaviors like an open circuit. Ony series resonance is a "short circuit" at resonance.

Comment: I just tested with an ammeter in the circuit you kindly supply, and it marks 0A before the resistence and no current before the LC loop, also in this case where you recalculated Zt, whats the phase of the impedance? (Im guessing 0)

Comment: [basic links](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10+%2B1%2F%281%2F+%28i*2*pi+*+60+*+0.796%29+%2B++1%2F%281%2F%28i*2*pi*60*8.84E-6%29%29%29)

Comment: Thanks so much, Zt was not right.